# Apple LLVM 6.0 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, iphone

XCode 5で作ったプロジェクトをXCode 6で開いたら、こちらのエラーが出ていてビルド出来ません。
解決策をご教授願います。

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/username/Documents/XCode/Projects/Projects/CollecCell.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

試行錯誤してみましたがお手上げです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これまでに試したことや確認したことを共有できますか? 問題解決の糸口になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

英語版のこちらにも似たような質問がありました。  
ご参考まで。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540973/clang-error-no-such-file-or-directory

> I eventually fixed the problem by just deleting the files in Xcode and re-adding them. Would be good to understand why this happened though. –  Snow Crash Nov 24 '12 at 12:35

---

> I faced the same problem. Nothing helps me: neither re-adding, nor cleaning project, derivedData, nor setting paths manually. Then I found out, that the path to the group, where I wanted to add my file, was path to nowhere. I set existing path to my group and than files were added correctly. –  Accid Bright Sep 5 '14 at 13:45

Answer (score 0):

まったく同じ内容の質問が英語版にありました。
ビルドターゲットの設定を見直すということのようですが。

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052293/apple-llvm-6-0-error